# Error when adding WMS layer in OpenLayers from a geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I try to add wms layer from geoserver:

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(name, 'http://'+ self.objSettings.ip + ':' + self.objSettings.port + self.objSettings.wms,
    {
        srs: 'EPGS:4326',
        layers: name,
        styles: '',
        transparent: true,
    },
    {
        isBaseLayer: false,
        singleTile: true,
        opacity: 0.8,
        visibility: true,
    }
);
```

But point appears at (0,0).[image]

Gdalinfo of geotiff, which I use for creating a layer:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: pkmanager_295557648395020263_undefined.TIF
Size is 299, 409
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (45.163320799224309,39.151851082312362)
Pixel Size = (0.001392666663209,-0.000743564600941)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  45.1633208,  39.1518511) ( 45d 9'47.95"E, 39d 9' 6.66"N)
Lower Left  (  45.1633208,  38.8477332) ( 45d 9'47.95"E, 38d50'51.84"N)
Upper Right (  45.5797281,  39.1518511) ( 45d34'47.02"E, 39d 9' 6.66"N)
Lower Right (  45.5797281,  38.8477332) ( 45d34'47.02"E, 38d50'51.84"N)
Center      (  45.3715245,  38.9997921) ( 45d22'17.49"E, 38d59'59.25"N)
Band 1 Block=299x6 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=0
Band 2 Block=299x6 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=0
Band 3 Block=299x6 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=0
Band 4 Block=299x6 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  NoData Value=0
```

Url, which is called:

`http://192.168.200.67:8081/geoserver/sf/wms?height=1024&width=1024&layers=sf:pkmanager_295557648395020263_undefined&request=GetMap&service=wms&styles=raster&format_options=SUPEROVERLAY:false;KMPLACEMARK:false;KMSCORE:40;KMATTR:true;&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/vnd.google-earth.kmz&transparent=false&version=1.1.1`

Comment: You need to include the actual http reference that is used, using a Debugger to see what is actually being called. What is self.objSettings.wms, hard to answer without all the information ..Please post the actual url being called using firebug or similar ..

Comment: Http reference look like http://192.168.200.79:8081/geoserver/sf/wms?height=1024&width=1024&layers=sf:pkmanager_295557648395020263_undefined&request=GetMap&service=wms&styles=raster&format_options=SUPEROVERLAY:false;KMPLACEMARK:false;KMSCORE:40;KMATTR:true;&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/vnd.google-earth.kmz&transparent=false&version=1.1.1

Comment: Can you add it to your question please .. it comes up as a link here ..

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Are you intending to download a kmz file? Have you styled the layer with SLD or are you trying to extract the shape file data as a Kml file which is vector data? I think you need top be  a lot more specific with how you has set up the layers in geoserver. Vector data usually goes on a Vector Layer, not a WMS Layer

Comment: What projection is your map in? Probably change the format as Mark C suggests as well.